# Magento Back office RTL support theme

Tags: adminhtml, theme

I am creating a Persian Magento website and using magento C.E  1.9.2.1 but when i try to change admin back office , see it translates the word and text correctly but everything is **LEFT TO RIGHT** yet.

I need a back office(admin) **Right To Left** theme, appreciate your suggestion and help